# Linear regression on time series and configuration selection

Tags: python, time-series, regression, linear-regression, feature-selection

I have a time series dataset with daily data of dependent variable and independent variables, some of which are impressions in different channels.

- Dependent variable is `dependent var`
- Independent are `impressions, channel, genre, duration, video_type` etc. Total length of the time series is 700 obj - days.

In fact, the dependent variable data is valid by day, but the independent variable (impression) data has a more detailed format - hours and minutes (dataset length over 40k rows). And they depend on the `day of the week`, `hours`, `formats`, `genres`, `channels` and `duration`.

> There can be several dozen different types of videos in one day with different formats, hours and durations, etc. And impressions depends on them.

But, since the model is based on daily data of the dependent variable, the entire dataset was aggregated into daily data in a pivot table and merged with `dependent var`. This way I can choose the drill-down of the data to build the model. For example, the sum of impressions by day for genres, duration, etc., in order to then use them as regressors.

> Multiple linear regression OLS was chosen as a model, since the interpretability and the ability to get the contributions of factors are important to me: impressions by day, impressions by hours, impressions by genre, impressions by video duration

The impression' detailed dataset looks like this:

| impression | day | hour | channel | genre | duration | video_type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 535 | 0 | 15 | channel_1 | genre_1 | 60 | type_1 |
| 684 | 4 | 16 | channel_2 | genre_2 | 120 | type_1 |
| 976 | 6 | 19 | channel_3 | genre_3 | 60 | type_3 |
| 234 | 3 | 20 | channel_4 | genre_4 | 80 | type_2 |
| 754 | 1 | 21 | channel_5 | genre_5 | 100 | type_3 |

I'm not sure how best to do this.

1. If we build a model on detailed daily data on the number of impressions per day per hour by genre and duration (`impressions_day_hour_genre_duration` factor), then the number of factors is 3 times greater than the number of observations and a sparse matrix with 1-5 non-zero values ​​is obtained. I'm sure this is not the best idea.

```
general_df_distil.pivot_table(
    index=['data'], 
    columns=['day', 'hour', 'channel','genre', 'duration', 'video_type'], 
    values=['impression'], 
    aggfunc=np.sum
)
```

2. Build a panel model with fixed effects by transforming the original dataset into the desired form. To get impressions contributions by day, hour, genre and duration.
3. Build several models of multiple linear regression OLS. Model by `impressions_days`, model by `impressions_hours`, model by `impressions_genres`, etc. Again, I doubt the reliability of this idea, since the values ​​of the sum of relative contributions will differ for all models (it is logical that they should not differ)

```
general_df_distil.pivot_table(index=['data'], columns=['genre'], values=['impression'], aggfunc=np.sum)
```

4. It is not a good idea to use `impressions` in their pure form, and include `days`, `hours`, `genres` and `duration` in the model as dummy variables, since the dummy variables of days can be interpreted as a seasonal component, but I use `Fourier harmonics` as a seasonal component.
5. Is it worth looking at Structural Equation Modeling (SEM)?

I also looked at `sklearn` decision trees and `catboost` gradient boosting as models - since I can get the importance of features. But I need interpretability.

**Summary:**
I need to build a model based on daily traffic data in which I can clearly assess the impact of impressions fatures by days of the week, hours, genres, channels on dependent traffic. Provided that on the same day there may be impressions on different channels / genres / hours.

**The questions:** Are there any more correct and elegant ways to solve this problem? What models are worth paying attention to in order to implement an interpretable model for the factors that I have?

*I will supplement / correct the description if everything is not clear in the current one*

Comment: Have you tried [SHAP](https://github.com/slundberg/shap) to explain the output of any ML model? When it comes to interpretability, SHAP shows features that each contributes to pushing the model's output from the base value. I think it fits partly your problem definition.

Comment: @Mario Thanks! I know about SHAP and LIME, but in my case I am at the stage of defining the model specification and its type. + OLS allows you to explicitly evaluate contributions.

Comment: I would determine contributions using PRE. Make a series of models where you omit one predictor of interest and compare it to the RSS of the "base" model.

Comment: @fthomson Thank you! PRE is a good method for evaluating contribution of factor, but i still don’t know on which configuration  to use it. I cannot take a specification with more than 2k features as a base model, because there are only 700 daily observations of dep variable.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you trying to predict in your model. Are you trying to determine highest contributions to impression score? Do you want it grouped by day? hour? It depends on what you are trying to model.

Comment: @fthomson Summarized the basic idea in **Summary**.